# Got this question in my school book, can't understand the logic in the program or the answer given in the answer key either(Java)

Tags: java, object, oop

> What will be printed at step 4, after executing the steps 1,2 and 3?

```
boolean b1=new boolean("TRUE");   //step 1
boolean b2=new boolean("true");   //step 2
boolean b3=new boolean("JUNK");   //step 3
System.out.println(""+b1+b2+b3);  //step 4
```

*The following options are given to choose from an answer:*

(a) Compiler error
(b) RunTime error
(c) `truetruefalse`
(d) `truetruetrue`

*The correct answer is*

> (c) trutruefalse

Can someone explain the logic?

Comment: Nothing will be printed because the above is not valid java code and will not compile.

Comment: Does that mean the question or answer key is wrong?

Comment: You mean `new Boolean` and not `new boolean`

Comment: You probably meant the `Boolean` class instead of the `boolean` primitive. `new boolean("True")` is not valid java but `new Boolean("True")` would be. Capitalization is important when programming.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS I considered that too, I guess the question is wrong then, because that's exactly how it is given in the book.

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**If** you mean `Boolean` instead of `boolean`, then the correct answer is `(c) truetruefalse` because if you look at the java source code, you will find:

```
public Boolean(String s) {
    this(parseBoolean(s));
}
```

that call:

```
public static boolean parseBoolean(String s) {
    return "true".equalsIgnoreCase(s);
}
```

so if your string is not `true`(with any case) then you will get `false`.

---

Note that: `new Boolean(String s)` is deprecated since Java 9.

Answer (score 1):

It prints `"truetruefalse"` because both `"true"` and `"TRUE"` are valid strings for `true`.  Anything else would return `false`.

Note:  You need to use `Boolean` and not `boolean`.  And the constructor is deprecated.

Best to use `boolean b4 = Boolean.parseBoolean("someString");` when assigning to primitive boolean type or `Boolean b4 = Boolean.valueOf("someString");` when assigning to a Boolean Object.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't tried running this on your local machine, I highly suggest so. There are two things going on here.

To start with, three Boolean objects are created though there must be a typo as the correct way is upper case B i.e. `new Boolean()`. If you have a look at the Javadocs this constructor, it says

> Allocates a Boolean object representing the value true if the string
> argument is not null and is equal, ignoring case, to the string
> "true". Otherwise, allocates a Boolean object representing the value
> false.

so b1 & b2 are set to Boolean.TRUE and b3 is set to Boolean.FALSE.

Lastly, you cannot apply the `+` operator on boolean objects. But if you wanted to print it, you have to tell the compiler that the object it needs to print is a string and to do that you have to add the `""` at the beginning of the concatenation.

The following code will print "123" and "6" respectively

```
System.out.println("" +1+2+3);
System.out.println(1+2+3);
```

The reason for that is, the first line has the method argument starting with String whereas the second one is doing a calculation (evaluating the expression) and printing the result.